# Visualize class dependencies in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have started a new job and there are 100k lines of code written in Python 2.7 across four different repos.

The code is sometimes quite nested, with many library imports and a complex class structure, and no documentation.

I want to create a graph of the dependencies in order to understand the code better.

I have not found anything on the internet except https://pypi.org/project/pydeps/ but that is not working for some unknown [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73826944/pydeps-not-working-nameerror-global-name-c-is-not-defined).

The solution should either query all python files in the four repos automatically, or it should take a single python file with some function call I have saved, and then go through all dependencies and graphically display them.

A good solution would also display which arguments or (keyword arguments) are passed on, or how often a function is used within the 100k lines of code to understand which methods are more important etc. This is not a strong requirement, however.

If someone could post one or more python libraries (or VSCode extensions) that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you also download Graphviz? Its needed for Pydeps.--> http://www.graphviz.org/download/

Comment: Dear @Damiaan, many thanks for asking. I installed it, but the error remains. I have not found a solution for the pydeps error but have opened a new ticket under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73826944/pydeps-not-working-nameerror-global-name-c-is-not-defined